# Why don't replacement bulbs work in my outdoor fixtures?

Tags: lighting

I have three outdoor lamps that sit above my front door and garage. The light bulbs recently went out so I thought I would replace them all and keep them uniform. The ones I removed were 60w, bright white, LED, looks like candelabra base. I tried replacing them with three different light bulbs which I thought were similar, but none of them worked!

I got them from Home Depot and another local lighting place. However, I found a filament light bulb from GE at the bottom of my closet and tried it out and it worked! However, I don't want to use a filament light bulb because I don't want to keep on changing them. My understanding is that it shouldn't matter if it is LED vs filament. Correct? So what am I doing wrong here?

Here is the [light bulb](https://www.homedepot.com/p/EcoSmart-60-Watt-Equivalent-B11-Dimmable-E12-Candelabra-Flame-Bent-Tip-Clear-Glass-LED-Vintage-Edison-Light-Bulb-Daylight-3-Pack-FG-04189/316021843) I used from Home Depot. Here is [what I found](https://www.ebay.com/itm/404121607354?chn=ps&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-213727-13078-0&mkcid=2&itemid=404121607354&targetid=4580840333842766&device=c&mktype=&googleloc=&poi=&campaignid=603247654&mkgroupid=1235852063340202&rlsatarget=pla-4580840333842766&abcId=9316139&merchantid=51291&msclkid=72c58dc629531886c8afe9071526abd7) that did work.

Troubleshooting performed.

1. I tried each light bulb in different sockets to make sure.
2. I turned the breaker on and off just incase. No change.
3. I kept one of the old LED light bulbs one of the sockets to use as my constant. It still is working.

Comment: 1 - Are you sure the old bulb was LED? An LED bulb @ 60W would be a *huge* amount of light. I'm having trouble even finding a bulb that big - I found a 35W that is rated at 4,690 lumens - equivalent to a 300W incandescent floodlight - which is **huge**. If the old bug actually says "60W" on it then it is probably incandescent - and an LED equivalent would be ~ 7W - 9W. 2 - Any special switch - dawn/dusk? motion detector? Both of those *can* (but not always) leak current through the bulbs when "off", which works great with incandescent but either doesn't work at all with LED or causes blinking.

Comment: 3 LED bulbs (or incandescent bulbs) going out at exactly the same time is highly suspect, for one thing. Have you described the actual situation accurately? You can [edit] to clarify or correct as needed.

Comment: Did you test the old bulb? Are you sure the bulb went out rather than the circuit going out?

Comment: you'll probably have to replace the lamps once incandescent bulbs become impossible to get; i'm in the same boat with my matched set of outdoor lights. There's an older triac dimmer in them that simply won't play nice with any LED bulb i can find. I will try to jumper across the triac to kill the dimming aspect, but I don't expect most folks will be comfortable doing that surgery...

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I think that's 60w "equivalent", not that the bulb itself consumes 60w. I wonder how long they'll keep marketing them that way - I pay zero attention to that anymore and look exclusively at the lumens output which is much more useful, anyway.

Comment: @FreeMan I know you know how it works. But OP stated "**60w, bright white, LED, looks like candelabra base**".  I don't recall ever seeing an "LED 60W equivalent" that actually said 60W **on the bulb**. Only on the packaging. Which makes me think that the only part OP truly knows is "60W, bright white". Since for that matter it often doesn't say "LED" **on the bulb"" either, and incandescents didn't say "this is not an LED" or "incandescent".

Comment: OP linked to '60W equivalent' bulbs so that's almost certainly what they meant.